# Is it possible to avoid temp files when a Java method expects Reader/Writer arguments?

Tags: java, stream

I'm calling a method from an external library with a (simplified) signature like this:

```
public class Alien
{
    // ...
    public void munge(Reader in, Writer out) { ... }
}
```

The method basically reads a String from one stream and writes its results to the other. I have several strings which I need processed by this method, but none of them exist in the file system. The strings can get quite long (ca 300KB each). Ideally, I would like to call munge() as a filter:

```
public void myMethod (ArrayList<String> strings)
{
    for (String s : strings) {
        String result = alienObj.mungeString(s);
        // do something with result
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the Alien class doesn't provide a mungeString() method, and wasn't designed to be inherited from. Is there a way I can avoid creating two temporary files every time I need to process a list of strings? Like, pipe my input to the Reader stream and read it back from the Writer stream, without actually touching the file system?

I'm new to Java, please forgive me if the answer is obvious to professionals.

Comment: My God, I must have been blind. Thanks for the fast answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily avoid temporary files by using any/all of these:

- [`CharArrayReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayReader.html) / [`CharArrayWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/CharArrayWriter.html)
- [`StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html) / [`StringWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html)
- [`PipedReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedReader.html) / [`PipedWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PipedWriter.html)

A sample `mungeString()` method could look like this:

```
public String mungeString(String input) {
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  alienObj.munge(new StringReader(input), writer));
  return writer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`StringReader`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html)

[`StringWriter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringWriter.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are welling to work with binary arrays in-memory like you do in C# then I think the PipedWriter & PipedReader are the most convenient way to do so. Check this:

[Is it possible to avoid temp files when a Java method expects Reader/Writer arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433265/is-it-possible-to-avoid-temp-files-when-a-java-method-expects-reader-writer-argu)

Comment: Why would you answer to a question with a link to the question itself?